# Prepared Statement Not Fetching All Results

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a prepared statement which is grabbing rentals in a storage facility and putting them in a list to keep track of in the back end when they are coming up due. The problem I am having is that when the statement outputs the list, if more than one person has the same number of days until they are due, the list only shows one of those renters. I have this is my prepared statement:

```
SELECT rentals.rental_startdate,
       rentals.rental_renewdate,
       rentals.rental_duedate,
       rentals.rental_latedate, 
       rentals.rental_status,
       rentals.rental_balance,
       units.unit_id,
       units.unit_number,
       units.unit_status,
       users.user_id,
       users.user_fname,
       users.user_lname,
       @var := DATEDIFF(rentals.rental_renewdate,CURRENT_DATE) AS days 
  FROM rentals
 INNER JOIN units ON units.unit_id = rentals.unit_id
 INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = rentals.user_id
 WHERE rentals.rental_status=? 
 GROUP BY rentals.rental_renewdate HAVING days>=0 AND days<=?
 ORDER BY rentals.rental_renewdate ASC
```

The issue seems to be coming from the `HAVING days>=0 AND days<=?`. The days are equal to the notification period which is defined in a variable as 5 days. When I take that off I see everyone who us coming up due whether their rent is due in 5 days or 10 which we don't really want but it fixes the problem of only seeing one person who is going to be due in 3 days when there are really 2. Does anything look out of place that would cause this issue? I'm using `while($select -> fetch()) {` to select the rows.

Comment: did you run the query separately in the mysql monitor to see what the results are? Maybe the fetch is working perfectly and the query itself is "losing" records due to a logic bug

Comment: I think days is a character type, so you get a string compare

Comment: @MarcB I did, I'm getting the same records there that I am seeing on the website which is not correct.

Comment: @KamilG. So I should have something like rentals.days in my SELECT statement? It's not really a column in my database though.

Comment: @SpyderTech. I might have confused you with previous comment. Once again: When you are grouping data in your query, every column that appears in the SELECT clause should either appear in the GROUP BY clause or be aggregated with a function. Not following that you may get odd results.

Comment: @KamilG. Ah ok, Steve below is saying the same thing and that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add name data to your GROUP BY clause.

`GROUP BY  users.user_fname, users.user_lname, rentals.rental_renewdate`

Should do the trick